# How do I solve for x and y: x + 0.0467 + y = 1.000?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the isotopes for percent abundance question. I am looking over and answer and can't figure it out because of the math.

Here it goes. 1) Set up a system of two equations in two unknowns:

Let $x$ = isotopic abundance of Si-28 (as a decimal) 
Let $y$ = isotopic abundance of Si-30 (as a decimal)
Therefore:

$$(27.9769) (x) + (28.9765) (0.0467) + (29.9738) (y) = 28.0855$$
and

$$x + 0.0467 + y = 1.000$$

2) Rearrange the second equation to:

$$y = 1.000 - 0.0467 - x$$
then simplify it, substitute into the first equation and solve.

Comment: So far, there is nothing wrong with what you've done.  Now you substitute what $y$ equals into the first equation, and that'll give you an equation with only $x$ as the variable.  Then from there, you can solve for $x$.  Finally, whatever value you get for $x$ -- plug that into one of the two equations you started with, and solve for $y$, and you are done.

Comment: That's what I trying to determine. What are the values of x and y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you found that $y = 1.000 - 0.0467 - x$.  Also, you have the following equation:

$$27.9769x + (28.9765)(0.0467) + 29.9738y = 28.0855 $$

So we can plug in what we have for $y$ into this equation and get the equation:

$$27.9769x + (28.9765)(0.0467) + 29.9738(1.000 - 0.0467 - x) = 28.0855 $$

Solving for $x$ gives $x = 0.922293$.

Now, we need the $y$ value.  We can choose either of the two equations you started out with, and substitute the value we got for $x$ in order to solve for $y$.  I'll use the equation $$x + 0.0467 + y = 1.000$$

Substituting $0.922293$ for $x$ gives the equation

$$0.922293 + 0.0467 + y = 1.000 $$

and solving for $y$ gives $y = 0.031007$.

So, our solution is $(x,y) = (0.922293,0.031007)$.